# System cannot identify installed Python packages

Tags: python, macos, pip, macos-ventura

Any package installed through pip3 is declared to be 'successfully installed' but cannot be identified despite the path being included in the the `$PATH` environment variable.

So far have attempted the following:

- reinstalled Python
- Reset `$PATH` and manually added pip3 packages directory, found using `pip3 list -v`
- installing packages within a venv.

The issue is demonstrated below in the project directory `antons_pizza` on macOS Ventura 13.4 with zsh shell.

```
➜ echo $PATH                            
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

➜  antons_pizza pip3 show django                           
Name: Django
Version: 4.2.2
Summary: A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: asgiref, sqlparse
Required-by: 

➜  antons_pizza django admin startproject antons_pizza     
zsh: permission denied: django

➜  antons_pizza sudo django admin startproject antons_pizza
sudo: django: command not found
```

Then in the venv

```
➜  antons_pizza source antons_pizza_venv/bin/activate
(antons_pizza_venv) ➜  antons_pizza pip3 install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./antons_pizza_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.6.0 in ./antons_pizza_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from django) (3.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.3.1 in ./antons_pizza_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from django) (0.4.4)
(antons_pizza_venv) ➜  antons_pizza django admin startproject antons_pizza     
zsh: permission denied: django
(antons_pizza_venv) ➜  antons_pizza sudo django admin startproject antons_pizza
Password:
sudo: django: command not found
```

Comment: Check where django lies with `which django` and then check the permissions with `ls -la <path to django>`

Comment: @FlyingTeller `which django` gives `Django not found`

Comment: Have you tried `django-admin` instead of `django`

Comment: I have not, that was the issue. And of course it was 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the comments by @FlyingTeller, alas it was a simple typo.

I was trying to run `django admin` when the command is in fact `django-admin`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- First of all make sure that it has executable permissions:

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

- Now, the problem is when you execute some program with sudo it does not load a login shell environment before executing the command, so the default `PATH` from /etc/sudoers is used, and we get a `command not found` error.
- **Solution:**

1. open the `sudoers` file and add uncomment the `secure_path` variable and add your path in it.

```
sudo visudo
```

2. Find this line and uncomment it and add your path to it.

```
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

3. Then re-login, and now try to call Django with sudo.

> You can also use this temporary solution:

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" your_command
```